# Is there a way to change the phase of a wood texture?

Tags: texturing, modifiers, displacement, procedural

Is there a way to change the phase of the wood texture that is used for a Displacement Modifier?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIgOT.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2zpu.png]
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kQ9N.png]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a wave modifier instead?

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know about that modifier. Although, I do specifically want the wood texture, because it gives me Noises and Disturbance.